# flask sqlalchemy paginate() function does not get the same elements when run twice

Tags: python, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using a simple sqlalchemy paginate statement like this

items = models.Table.query.paginate(page, 100, False)

with page = 1. When running this command twice I get different outputs? If I run it with less element (e.g. 10) it gives me the same outputs when run multiple times? I thought for a paginate command to work it has to result in the same set each time it is called? 
cheers 
carl

Answer (score 0):

ok I don't know the answer to this question but ordering the query (order_by) solved my problem... I am still interested to know why paginate does not have an order by itself, because it basically means that without the order statement, paginate cannot be used to iterate through all elements?
cheers
carl